# Adjusting Grades After Throwing Out Exam Questions

Tags: exams, grading

I’m in nursing school and all exams are reviewed after they are taken, and the majority of the time some questions are thrown out after review.
The question I have is if questions are thrown out shouldn’t the point value of the remaining questions be adjusted?
We only receive points if we miss a question that has been thrown out. We don’t get credit for it if we get it correct, and the overall points are not adjusted. This seems wrong to me.

**Example**: A test has 100 questions with 1 point per question, and I get 85% right. Ten "bad" questions are then thrown out.

- If I got all 10 "bad" questions wrong, then the professor gives me 10 points back, and I get a 95%.
- But if I got all of them right, then the professor leaves my score at 85%.
- I think I should instead get 85/90 = 94% in the latter case.

Comment: Am I missing something? 85/90 is 94%

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I believe the OP means that they would still get 85 if 10 questions that they got correct were discarded according to this grading scheme, OP is that correct?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- yes 85/90 is 94. That’s my point. The exam questions become worth more points. The professor isn’t adjusting point values after throwing out questions.

Comment: @Esther yes you are correct.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the grading scheme isn’t adjusted either (or the points count directly for something else)? Also, what do you mean by: “We only receive points if we miss a question that has been thrown out.”? If and only if you do not answer a discarded question, you receive extra points?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I think "miss a question" here means "give a wrong answer to a question".

Comment: Instead of "question thrown out" it's "every answer to the question is counted as correct"

Comment: I’m sorry it’s still unclear to me what the situation and problem is.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Common sense would say so, but then the entire problem seems to be that common sense wasn’t applied in the first place (by those designing the grading mechanics).

Comment: Are you concerned that your class grade is supposed to be out of 500 points (say), and the professor is removing 10 of those from your test, but not reducing the total amount of points to 490?

Comment: This is very confusing. I attempted an edit based on what I understood of the problem. If I misunderstood, feel free to correct, but let's keep the example in this format so that it will be clear.

Comment: I don't think that this is an appropriate question for Academia SE.  While I have *assumptions* about what it means for the graders to "throw out" several questions, I have no idea what the actual practices at your institution are.  This seems like a question for your institution, not this website.

Comment: Why are questions thrown out? It matters a lot, actually.

Answer (score 2):

It may be based on a sensible premise - let us calculate the score as a **fraction of the questions a student got right**. This means that the final score after throwing some of the questions out would be `correct answers to the remaining questions / total number of the remaining questions`.

Using your examples as a basis (you got 85/100 initially, 10 questions were taken out):

- You got none of the "bad" questions right. Final score: 85/90 = 94%.
- You got all of the "bad" questions right. Final score: 75/90 = 83%.
- You got 5 of the "bad" questions right. Final score: 80/90 = 89%.

As you can see, if all of your answers to the "bad" questions were correct, your score actually goes down! From a professor's perspective, it then makes sense to keep it at the higher value between the two (ruling it in the students' favor each time), so that students would not riot over the adjustments.

The rationale for the questions to be removed in the first place may be that they were found to be too ambiguous, and multiple students have successfully argued their case. An alternative approach would be simply to accept multiple options as correct after an appeal. The difference between the two approaches yields 85/90=94% vs 95/100=95%, and is a touch more extreme at the lower end of the scale (60/90=67%, 70/100=70%).

Still, this mostly would not make a break the score the way you are envisioning it, and the scheme described is more consistent than just giving students "freebies". Remember, exam scores are not the end goal, your knowledge is :)